# Blank space under the footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a webpage and I found out that on some pages there is extra blank space below the footer and when I reload the page it just disappears.

This happens on almost all pages except *Home* and *Contact Us*.

I have just tried looking for on Inspect Element on Chrome and Firefox
and adding the style

```
.footer{
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

but still can't find the source of the problem.

Here is the link http://event1930.cgr-dev.com/services

Comment: it is working in chrome 49

Comment: you'll need to provide some code in your post, not a website link, the shortest possible in order to be able to reproduce the issue... I think it has nothing to do with CSS, it's probably one of your js tricks you have on the site that plays games with you... *edit:* I see you're using WordPress, so start by deactivating your plugins one by one, then with deactivating your js animation mojo one by one, and you'll find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this issue may be coming from the animation tied to the bounceInUp class. This is the rule: `translateY(-2000px);`. Any of your pages that has a button with that class seem to have the issue. Try reducing the pixel value on that animation and it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time, this was the problem that was driving me crazy jajajaja. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.footer{
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `padding-bottom: 30px;` from #footer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.footer{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Also try messing with the position and display setting.